# C++ get integer buffer array from integer and do Java like outStream.writeInt()

Tags: java, c++, buffer

This is java code for converting int to buffer array:

```
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class bytes {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        DataOutputStream output = new DataOutputStream(buffer);
        output.writeInt(1000);

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(buffer.toByteArray()));
    }

}
```

This is C++ code for converting int to buffer array:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>


void getBigEndienInt(uint32_t& num) {

    num = ((num >> 24) & 0xff) | // move byte 3 to byte 0
        ((num << 8) & 0xff0000) | // move byte 1 to byte 2
        ((num >> 8) & 0xff00) | // move byte 2 to byte 1
        ((num << 24) & 0xff000000); // byte 0 to byte 3
}

void intToCharArray(uint32_t* buffer, uint32_t in)
{
    buffer[0] = ((in >> 24) & 0xFF);
    buffer[1] = ((in >> 16) & 0xFF);
    buffer[2] = ((in >> 8) & 0xFF);
    buffer[3] = ((in >> 0) & 0xFF);

}
bool isLittleEndian()
{
    short int number = 0x1;
    char* numPtr = (char*)&number;
    return (numPtr[0] == 1);
}

int main()
{
    if(isLittleEndian()){
        std::cout << "Using little endien...\n";
    }
    uint32_t num = 1000;
    getBigEndienInt(num);

    uint32_t buffer[sizeof(int)];
    intToCharArray(buffer, num);

    for (auto& el : buffer) {
        std::cout << (el & 0xff) << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;


    
}
```

My issue is here: Java returns [0, 0, 3, -24] and C++ code returns [232, 3, 0, 0]. I wan't it to be same as in Java. I tried using little and big endien but result is same, just different order.

Comment: Your C++ code writes little-endian, while Java writes big-endian. `232` and `-24` are one and the same - you are just looking at this value as unsigned sometimes and as signed other times. (Hint: `232 == 256 - 24`)

Comment: The `htonl` function available on many targets may make your job easier.

Comment: Drop `getBigEndienInt` call. Your `intToCharArray` stores the number in big endian, regardless of the underlying architecture (which is the right thing to do). By calling `getBigEndienInt` first, you basically flip the order twice.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik How do I do conversion?

Comment: Conversion of what to what else? I don't understand the question. I believe your program would work as you expect if you simply remove `getBigEndienInt(num);` line from `main`.

Comment: Does not work, it is still same values just different order.

Comment: Bytes from java and from c++ are not same. From C++ I get 0 0 3 232 and from Java I get [0, 0, 3, -24].

Comment: They are exactly the same. -24 signed is the save value as 232 unsigned. Java char is signed, c's is unsigned.

Comment: You get the same numerical values, you just print them differently. Try `std::cout << int(el)`, you should probably get a signed integer from C++, too.